Flask email-validator installation via terminal does not work; yet is successful when using Pycharm Python Interpreter
I am trying to use the "email-validator" package to create forms using Flask, written in Pycharm (Python 3.12).
When I first ran the code, I received this message: "Exception: Install 'email_validator' for email validation support.". I successfully installed email_validator using pip install, but the program would still not run.
I tried again "pip install email-validator" and got the following messages:
Requirement already satisfied: email-validator in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: dnspython>=2.0.0 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from email-validator) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0.0 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from email-validator) (3.4)
After some research, I learned that my Terminal defaults to a python v3.11 folder situated under Anaconda, which was the previous editor I used; I recently started working with Pycharm, as suggested by the online course I am taking, and am using python 3.12.
To solve the issue I tried running a few online suggestions:

changing the terminal path using export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3.12:$PATH",
change: "source path/to/.venv/bin/activate" followed by "pip3 install email-validator",
pip install -e email-validator
deleting Anaconda (my own idea), but wasnt able to completely delete it.

Finally, I gave up the terminal and tried installation using Python Interpreter in Pycharm, and it worked right away. I am new to coding and havent yet learned about environments. I have no idea about what the commands above were doing, and would like to understand what is happening. Would anyone please explain, or point me to any helpful resource about environment basics?
